# Javascript Date add days

Tags: javascript

```
var date = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();          
daysinadvance = document.getElementById('AdvanceDays').value;
date2.setDate(date.getDate()+daysinadvance);
console.log(date2 + date + daysinadvance);

Fri Jan 28 2022 18:13:43 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)  
Mon Apr 28 2014 18:13:43 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)
60
```

If I pass in a directly typed number so + 60, it works fine but using the variable, I get a date in 2022.  All I would like is the date2 to be current date + 60 days so I can update my validation.

Any help please?

Comment: don't forget that you're pulling a STRING with that `.value` call and then trying to do math with it. If JS is producing a string concatentation, e.g. `28+6=286` instead of `28+6=34`, you'll be passing wonky day values back to setDate().

Comment: There could be one issue parsing the value(`input type="text"` will return *string* value ie, "60").  otherwise it is working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the value to a number first, e.g. with the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) operator:

```
var daysinadvance = +document.getElementById('AdvanceDays').value;
//                  ^ unary plus
```

Otherwise `daysinadvance` will be a string and you are doing string concatenation.

Comment: @13ruce1337, just 9 bytes more than you need ;)